# Identifing the single largest number occurring in a file

Tags: java, coding-style, numbers, extract, long-integer

Let's assume a text file is a Math text book. How should I code to find out the largest number in that file? I'm aware of using `StringTokens`, `parseLong`, `split`, etc. But I can't figure out a proper way to combine them.

To be precise, let's say that text has something like:

```
Chapter 3.5

Million has 6 zeros. Ex. 6,000,000
Billion has 9 zeros. Ex. 9,000,000,000
Trillion has 12 zeros. Ex. 8,000,000,000,000
```

The largest number is `8000000000000`. How do I extract that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Math books contain lots of different forms of numbers... scientific notation, integers, complex numbers (for which I assume you want the absolute value), etc., and some notation may get unrecognizably mangled if you just scanned a printed textbook... Before starting you should examine enough of the text stream visually to identify all the different number formats you're interested in.  What about things like factorials? If you encounter the string `100!` do you want to count it as 100 or as the factorial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Scanner interface.  This code assumes you pass in the file path as the first argument.  The Scanner interface handles commas in numbers. I use BigInteger to handle any size number.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BigInteger biggestNumber = null;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[0]));
        while( s.hasNext() ){
            if( s.hasNextBigInteger() ){
                BigInteger number = s.nextBigInteger();
                if( biggestNumber == null || number.compareTo(biggestNumber) == 1 ){
                    biggestNumber = number;
                }
            }
            else {
                s.next();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Biggest Number: " + biggestNumber.toString());
    }
```

You can play with an online example at: http://ideone.com/zKI5rM .  It doesn't read from a file but uses a string in the code instead.

One place this would fail is if the book splits large numbers across lines. I'm not sure what your source material is, but that is something to keep in mind.

Comment: THANKS A BUNCH MAN! This was exactly what I needed. It's simple, easy to read and short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigInteger`

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String line = "215,485,454,648,464";
        String line1 = "5,454,546,545,645";

        List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

        list.add(new BigInteger(line.replaceAll(",", "")));
        list.add(new BigInteger(line1.replaceAll(",", "")));

        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println("largest: " + list.get(list.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

> **Output**:  `largest: 215485454648464`

For your situation

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("yourFile.txt");
    List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

        String number = token[5].trim();   // gets only the last part of String 
        list.add(new BigInteger(line.replaceAll(",", "")));
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.println("largest: " + list.get(list.size() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the largest number seen so far (initially, negative infinity), then go through the entire file extracting each number and if it's greater than the largest number you've stored, store it. At the end, the number stored is the largest number. Use double rather than long to account for very large numbers and noninteger numbers. The simple way to find all integers is to use a Scanner, feeding next() into parseDouble(...) and comparing anything that doesn't throw a NumberFormatException.

Comment: A double still won't account for very large numbers.  BigInteger will handle larger integers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to parse the text file line by line.

You can do this using regular expressions to see if you have any number formats located in the current line. If you do then you can check to see if it's larger than the previously found number.

Here is an excellent tutorial on regular expressions if you haven't came across them yet.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html